# Making music programmatically on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, audio

I'm totally naive when it comes to audio and music on the iPhone, or on any platform in general.

Say I wanted to make a simple piano app - *is it possible to generate the sounds for each key programmatically?*

Or *would I have to provide say a .wav file for every possible sound?*

I'm wondering how programs like GarageBand are able to provide such diverse sounds - could it be that they have a file for every possible sound?

Or *is there a way to dynamically generate those kinds of sounds?*

**Edit**: I found [this most excellent article](http://www.hollance.com/2010/12/sound-synthesis-on-the-iphone/) describing exactly what I want to do, and the guy even has a sample project with a small piano with all sounds being generated programmatically.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can generate tones programmatically, as described in this [tutorial](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html?m=1). The example here shows you how to generate a pure sine wave using audio units.

Due to Fourier's theorem, any (periodic) continuous function can be expressed as the sum of sine functions of different amplitudes and phases. Using this, you can mix a few of these functions to simulate the sound of an instrument. However, this requires a lot of research and a deep understanding of wave mechanics and calculus, so it's not a trivial task.

Comment: Any idea how to get the tutorial project to run on the simulator with the 6.1 SDK? It only runs on device.

Comment: @mohabitar That probably has a reason (certain features are unavilable on the simulator.)

Answer (score 3):

Piano synthesisers are typically implemented with sample playback - and this includes real-world digital pianos too.  Typically considerably less than one sample per key is used in conjunction with a [DDS oscillator](http://www.electricdruid.net/index.php?page=info.dds).

Good quality digital piano synthesisers also carry samples for initial key-down, sustain, damper pedal open and key-up, at different keys velocities, which are then blended together.

There's source code for one in the [VST3 SDK](http://www.steinberg.net/nc/en/company/developer/sdk_download_portal.html)